# Finding UK deportation records for 1923 for Julius Brust

Tags: poland, united-kingdom, russia, 1920s, deportation-records

Julius Brust was Russian by birth.  He was convicted in 1923 of arson and Served 4 years imprisonment in UK, and then deported to Poland.

Where can I find records of that deportation?

Answer (score 2):

The file would have been held by the Home Office Immigration & Nationality Department (IND).  Now called UK Visas & Immigration:

https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration

Not all files of that age were retained so there’s a fair possibility that this was shredded after say 50 years. Alternatively it may have been weeded (to save space) leaving just a few core documents.  If the file does still exist it’s probably in the National Archives in Kew now. I’d start your search there.

(I worked for IND in the 1970s which is where my knowledge comes from).

Comment: Would this be the right place to start? I don't see a specific Research Guide for deportations. https://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/browse/r/h/C512

Comment: Yes. General files on Aliens looks the right area. The files themselves won't be on-line. I think you need a London based researcher to go to Kew to look them up. You could probably e-mail NAS and ask if the file you need exists.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer would be improved if you added that information to the main body of the answer.